# Is it possible to use a fixture inside pytest_generate_tests()?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a handful of fixtures in `conftest.py` that work well inside actual test functions. However, I would like to parameterize some tests using `pytest_generate_tests()` based on the data in some of these fixtures.

What I'd like to do (simplified):

```
-- conftest.py --
# my fixture returns a list of device names.
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def device_list(something):
    return ['dev1', 'dev2', 'dev3', 'test']

-- test001.py --
# generate tests using the device_list fixture I defined above.
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize('devices', itertools.chain(device_list), ids=repr)

# A test that is parametrized by the above function.
def test_do_stuff(devices):
    assert "dev" in devices

# Output should/would be:
dev1: pass
dev2: pass
dev3: pass
test: FAIL
```

Of course, the problem I'm hitting is that in `pytest_generate_tests()`, it complains that `device_list` is undefined. If I try to pass it in, `pytest_generate_tests(metafunc, device_list)`, I get an error.

```
E   pluggy.callers.HookCallError: hook call must provide argument 'device_list'
```

The reason I want to do this is that I use that `device_list` list inside a bunch of different tests in different files, so I want to use `pytest_generate_tests()` to parametrize tests using the same list.

Is this just not possible? What is the point of using `pytest_generate_tests()` if I have to duplicate my fixtures inside that function?

Comment: In case it helps, here's the error I get when I try to pass 'device_list' in to the pytest_generate_tests() function alongside metafunc. ```E   pluggy.callers.HookCallError: hook call must provide argument 'device_list'```

Answer (score 4):

From what I've gathered over the years, fixtures are pretty tightly coupled to pytest's post-collection stage. I've tried a number of times to do something similar, and it's never really quite worked out.

Instead, you could make a function that does the things your fixture would do, and call that inside the generate_tests hook. Then if you need it still as a fixture, call it again (or save the result or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I have been wanting to do something similar

So far the closest way I can see is to use https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/ library

You can then do something like:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def device_list(something):
    return ['dev1', 'dev2', 'dev3', 'test']


def test_do_stuff(subtests, devices):
    for device in devices:
        with subtests.test(msg="custom message", device=device):
            assert "dev" in device
```

Answer (score -1):

[This article](https://remusao.github.io/posts/pytest-param.html) somehow provides a workaround.

Just have a look at section **Hooks at the rescue**, and you're gonna get this:

```
import importlib

def load_tests(name):
    # Load module which contains test data
    tests_module = importlib.import_module(name)
    # Tests are to be found in the variable `tests` of the module
    for test in tests_module.tests.iteritems():
        yield test

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    """This allows us to load tests from external files by
    parametrizing tests with each test case found in a data_X
    file 
    """
    for fixture in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if fixture.startswith('data_'):
            # Load associated test data
            tests = load_tests(fixture)
            metafunc.parametrize(fixture, tests)
```

See, here it is loading the data by invoking the fixture that is prefixed with `data_`.

Comment: The article calling it "fixtures" is a bit misleading, because `tests` is not actually defined as a fixture, but a regular list module-level variable. This workaround doesn't work for actual fixtures decorated with `@pytest.fixture`.

Answer (score -1):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def device_list(something):
    device_list = ['dev1', 'dev2', 'dev3', 'test']
    return device_list
```

By using `autouse=True` in the pytest fixture decorator you can ensure that `pytest_generate_tests` has access to `device_list`.

Comment: Yes, with `autouse=True`, that fixture becomes visible in `metafunc.fixturenames` in the `pytest_generate_tests` hook... but that seems to be the only thing you can get, the name of the fixture, but can't get its value. An example would have been nice how to pass the arg values to `metafunc.parametrize`.