Pass a list of parameter to parametrize from a function
I have session scope fixture for initiating db connection
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def dconn():
    # Your database connection logic
    return "database_connection"

@pytest.fixture
def some_function(dconn):
    # Use dconn to generate data
    return [
        {"value1": "a", ....,"expected": "result1"},
        {"value1": "b", ....,"expected": "result2"},
        {"value1": "c", ....,"expected": "result3"}
    ]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", some_function))
def test_with_params(param):
    value1 = param["value1"]
     ....
    expected = parma["expected"]
    assert process_data(value1) == expected

it says some_function is not iterable. I changed to:
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", some_function()))
def test_with_params(param):
    value1 = param["value1"]
     ....
    expected = parma["expected"]
    assert process_data(value1) == expected

says fixtures cannot be called directly.
How to pass the list to parametrize?

there they are not passing the entire list in one function call, rather they are trying to call the function multiple times as per the list

Yes, fixtures cannot be called directly.
You can turn some_function to normal function:
def some_function():
    return [
        {"value": "value1", "expected": "result1"},
        {"value": "value2", "expected": "result2"},
        {"value": "value3", "expected": "result3"},
    ]

def process_data(data: str):
    return data.replace("value", "result")

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", some_function())
def test_with_params(param):
    value = param["value"]
    expected = param["expected"]
    assert process_data(value) == expected

Or even better:
def some_function():
    return [
        ("value1", "result1"),
        ("value2", "result2"),
        ("value3", "result3"),
    ]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value, expected", some_function())
def test_with_params(value: str, expected: str):
    assert process_data(value) == expected

Edit
You don't need to use parameterized.
def some_function(dconn):
    return [
        ("value1", "result1"),
        ("value2", "result2"),
        ("value3", "result3"),
    ]

def test_with_params(dconn):
    for value, expected in some_function(dconn):
        assert process_data(value) == expected
        # OR:
        assert process_data(value) == expected, f"{value=} {expected=}"

Edit 2
If you really want to use parameterized, you need to do some advanced stuff with pytest_generate_tests
def test_with_params(value_and_expected: dict):
    assert process_data(value_and_expected["value"]) == value_and_expected["expected"]

# conftest.py

def some_function(dconn):
    return [
        {"value": "value1", "expected": "result1"},
        {"value": "value2", "expected": "result2"},
        {"value": "value3", "expected": "result3"},
    ]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "value_and_expected" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        dconn = ""  # need to manually create DB connection without any fixture. `metafunc.config` might help with credentials
        value_and_expected = some_function(dconn)
        metafunc.parametrize("value_and_expected", value_and_expected)

But test collection will be slow and I wouldn’t recommend that.

I wanted to convert to normal function, but this function needs to connect to database.
i have a session scoped fixture dconn which i want to use in this normal function

@Santhosh Ah, I see your point. You really shouldn’t use parameterized then. See my edit

I dont want to use for loop, because it will not point out case failed for which param. else i am ready to use

@Santhosh after each assert line you can add a custom message to describe the test case. You can't do exactly what you want but you can achieve something similar with pytest_generate_tests. See Edit 2. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309558
